# (R) how to add own axis labels in plot

Tags: r, date

I have a plot that plots a time-series versus a variable. However, I want to replace the x-axis values in the plot (the time-series values) with another variable (the corresponding day).

The variables have been encoded in Date and time seperately. I have created a further variable 'day' to encode the weekday corresponding to the Date.

I then want to plot versus the time-series, but on the x-axis I want the 'day' displayed.

I cannot plot versus the weekday, since this gives an error (the variable is not numeric).

How can I do this? I have this currently:

```
 household$day <- weekdays(household$Date) #Where Date is 'Date' variable

 plot(as.numeric(household$Time), household$Global_active_power, type = "l", xaxt = 'n') # xaxt to remove the x-axis labels

 # Step 3: add the weekdays in household$day to the x-axis ...
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Use the function `axis`

Answer (score 0):

I mean using the axis() function to replace the values 'on' the x-axis.